# How can I read a .doc file in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, doc

I want to search and some changes on headers in my .doc file

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is by automating Office.

Some links:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316383

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/60975-office-automation/

Answer (score 0):

Using VSTO.

Try googling it.

Sample [here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/generateinvoicesvsto)